# Chip/Manufacturer ID - Possible ":C" logo

Tags: identification, cpu

Does anyone recognize this chip or manufacturer logo?  This chip is believed to be a circa 1990 25 MHz 386DX but the markings are a mystery.  The marking at the corner looks familiar (`:C` I think it's a manufacturer logo) but I can't place it.  Can anyone suggest what manufacturer or specific chip this is?

| **Chip** | **Possible logo** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Chip] | [image: Logo close-up] |

FWIW, `DS` was a prefix used by Dallas Semiconductor but the font doesn't seem right for their chips.

For context, the chip is on the board asked about in [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22378) on retrocomputing.se.

Comment: Related on retro computing: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22378

Comment: Might be Centaur Technologies, but they weren't active until 1995.  They made embedded X86 type processors if I remember right, but this is just a guess.

Comment: Thought it might be a Dallas Semiconductor "DS39399" since that laser mark does look similar to the Dallas Semi logo; they were acquired by Maxim Integrated (where I work) which was recently acquired by Analog Devices. But I think I can rule that out; I find a lot of Dallas Semi DS39* parts, but no DS393* parts.  Strange that there is both white topmark "DS39399.A 107M7NX" and also nearly invisible laser etch "23996 :C"

Comment: The marking on the chip in the lower right-hand corner is a company logo and indicates that the ceramic substrate was made by [Kyocera](https://global.kyocera.com/)

Comment: 2 additional photos here https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNbxm.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2P1s.jpg

Comment: Given the possibility of "Dallas Semiconductor", I note that the full motherboard photo has a chip (realtime clock?) clearly branded as "Dallas" at the lower right. Perhaps some kind of licensing between AMD and Dallas would explain the lack of branding on the CPU?

Answer (score 6):

Lower set of number is similar to this AMD part (from [this](https://www.computerbase.de/forum/threads/ich-benoetige-informationen-von-diesem-high-end-geraet-d.1996977/)) website:

[image]

Also the "logo" in the bottom right corner looks similar. Possibly the Kyocera logo, as @ vurp0 suggests in a comment, who made, and still make, hermetic ceramic IC packages.

[image]

Comment: The laser etching and the font match as well.

Comment: That looks a lot like the Kyocera logo in the corner. I don't know what their relation to AMD and this CPU is, though.

Comment: @vurp0 Kyocera make ceramic packages, possibly as simple as that.